# Data is not saving permanently in my localdatabase

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I would like to know why my data is not saving permanently in my local database. If I close my application and open it again. I cannot download the uploaded data. Its showing an error called **"The given key was not present in the dictionary”**
But I can download the file when the application is running. I mean, if the application is running and I upload a data to my grid, then download it its not throwing any error. If the application is closed and opened, that time if I try to download the same old file its throwing the error

My code

```
private void DownloadAttachment(DataGridViewCell dgvCell)
{
    string fileName = Convert.ToString(dgvCell.Value);

    //Return if the cell is empty
    if (fileName == string.Empty)
        return;

    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
    string fileExtension = fileInfo.Extension;

    byte[] byteData = null;

    //show save as dialog
    using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog())
    {
        //Set Save dialog properties
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Files (*" + fileExtension + ")|*" + fileExtension;
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save File as";
        saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = fileName;

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            cncInfoDataGridView.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = fileInfo.Name;
            byteData = _myAttachments[dgvCell.RowIndex];
            File.WriteAllBytes(saveFileDialog1.FileName, byteData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of database are you using?  If you'e using a file-based database like SQL Express make sure the data files aren't getting re-deployed when you build.

Comment: What is `_myAttachments`? Without knowing more (Database type, SQL Express etc) and are you using an ORM (nHibernate, EF) etc this is very hard to answer.

Comment: Adding to what D Stanley said, manually verify the files still exist in the file system.

Comment: What error are you getting when you reopen the application?

Comment: @DStanley localdatabse, i am not using any sql connection, i made a local data base and trying to run the app. My full project is here. Please check yourself <https://www.mediafire.com/?o30byobg53d923f>

Comment: I am getting error called " **The given key was not present in the dictionary **

Comment: You mean "LocalDB"?  That's a version of SQL Express.  My guess is that the MDB file is in your project folder and getting copied to bin\debug when you build.

Comment: @DStanley please go to this link <https://www.mediafire.com/?o30byobg53d923f%3E#u28ts1l8qpd0i> i have given my entire project.. can u look this tell me. Because i am sitting with this error for past four days

Comment: @DStanley yes local DB. The MDB is there in project folder as well as in bin\debug also. i can see two .sdf files . .sdf file is my MDB and its there in project folder and bin\debug

Comment: I don't have access to that location.  See if [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx) helps.

Comment: @DStanley that link was perfect. My local database is .sdf file. so my new copy is always copied to the bin folder. Which i dont want to worry.

Comment: The DB file is copied from the project directory to the bin directory the first time the project is built. Every subsequent time you build the project, the Date Modified property of the files is compared. If the file in the project folder is newer, it is copied to the bin folder, replacing the file that is currently there. If the file in the bin folder is newer, no files are copied. This setting persists any changes made to the data during run time, meaning that every time you run your application and save changes to the data, those changes are visible the next time you run your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok try this it will perfectly work. If its a server based-database then try this..

```
   string s = cncInfoDataGridView.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   File.WriteAllBytes(saveFileDialog1.FileName, byteData);
   byteData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
```

If you are using a localdatabase then try below code.

```
SqlCeConnection cnn = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.CncConnectionString);
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileDialog.FileName);
            byte[] SqlTypeBlob = File.ReadAllBytes(fileDialog.FileName);
            cncInfoDataGridView.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = fileInfo.Name;
            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO CncInfo (Drawings) VALUES (@DATA)", cnn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
            cmd.Parameters["@DATA"].Value = SqlTypeBlob;
            cnn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnn.Close();
```

if anything else then this

```
  byteData = _myAttachments[dgvCell.ColumnIndex];
  File.WriteAllBytes(saveFileDialog1.FileName, byteData);
```

If this works please close this and give me a approve click for my answer. Peace out!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot Milan .. i got the answer by your post. Thank you you are great

Answer (score 0):

(for posterity)

It sounds like your data file is getting recopied every time you build your project.  You need to adjust your project settings so that the data file does not get overwritten until it needs to (due to a structure change, etc.)

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx) should help you get your project set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I made a custom made database, in which I will be storing all my uploaded data. Thanks to all my dear friends who guided me to set my brand new database..